# How to start a java ecplise program that takes an optional command line argument, which is the name of the file

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

So after I create a **Java class**, I am not sure how to begin or put the codes for the instructions below:

> The format of this file is a list of persons'names, one per line. The program will read these names and store them in an array.

If no command line argument is given, the program will simply create an empty array, used to store names.

Help? :)

Answer (score 1):

select the program and *right-click* and select run configuration.

On the run configuration window you will see **Arguments** tab enter the file name  in **program arguments**.

This file name can be accessed under the **String []** parameter passed in **main** method of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer this GUI based steps, which will help you easily to fix it.

**Step - 1. Right click on Project -> Run -> Run Configuration.**

[image]

**Step - 2 : Select "Arguments" tab. and enter value into "Program arguments" whatever you want to pass from Command Line.**

[image]

**Step - 3 : Place add following code into your class to apply correct logic as per your wise,**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args.length == 0){ // if no command line argument is given, then args.length becomes 0, means if block execute..
            // simple create an array to store names....
        }

    }
```