# What does it mean by taking an optional command line argument

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

What does it mean by taking an optional command line argument? And the rest of the paragraph.

When I start, the program takes an optional command line argument, which is the name of a file. The content of this file is a list of persons' names, one per line. The program will read these names and store them in an array. If no command line argument is given, the program will simply create an empty array, used to store names.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = null;
    boolean isFile = false;

    while (isFile == false){
        System.out.println("Input file name:");
        String fileName = sc.next();
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);

        if(inputFile.exists()){
            input = new Scanner(inputFile);
            isFile = true;
```

Comment: Your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149788/how-to-start-a-java-ecplise-program-that-takes-an-optional-command-line-argument) has some really good information and answers regarding this? Are you confused by a specific part? Can we see what your class looks like so far?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner input = null;
  boolean isFile = false;
  
  while (isFile == false){
   System.out.println("Input file name:");
   String fileName = sc.next();
   File inputFile = new File(fileName);
   
   if(inputFile.exists()){
    input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    isFile = true;
   }
  } 
 } 
}

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  if(args.length == 0){
   System.out.println("Input filename:");

Comment: i'm testing both ways but i'm not sure if the first one is right

Comment: Add the code to your question (by Editing the question), not as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Typically signature of your main method goes as `public static void main(String[] args)`. Here `String[] args` is your command line argument. All command line arguments passed to the program will be stored in `args` array.

So, suppose when you run your "Sort" program as `java Sort friends.txt` then here "friends.txt" is what you will call as first command line argument and `args[0]` will have value as `friends.txt`.

Now suppose you run your "Sort" program as `java Sort` then this is called as invoking program with **no command line argument** and `args[0]` will have value as `null`.

### Mandatory command line arguments

If you have following code, then it can be said that command line argument is mandatory because you do not want to proceed if there is no command line argument supplied.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if(args[0] == null){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

### Optional command line arguments

Now, consider below code. Here since you are proceeding is code execution and not exiting even when there is no command line argument or in other words your program can still process/do something even without any command line argument being supplied so it means command line argument is optional. **If your code is not dependent on command line argument to be passed and will function even without it then it means your command line argument is optional.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if(args[0] != null){
        //do something with args[0]
    }
    // Do rest of the things...
}
```

Your case looks like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> personNames = new ArrayList<String>(); //It cannot be Array because size cannot be known until file is read.
    if(args[0] != null){
        //read file.
        //update personNames arraylist
        //convert to array, if it is really required
    } else{
        //this makes command line argument as optional, simply convert to array if really required and it would be of size 0.
    }
    // Do rest of the things...
}
```

---

Further readings:

- [Command line argument from Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).
- [Processing command line arguments in Java: Case closed](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074849/core-java/processing-command-line-arguments-in-java--case-closed.html)

Answer (score 0):

A command line argument can be passed to your program when running it. The arguments are passed as a string array into the main method (this is the the 'String[] args' thing is for in the main method!) For example:

> The user enters command-line arguments when invoking the application and specifies them after the name of the class to be run. For example, suppose a Java application called Sort sorts lines in a file. To sort the data in a file named friends.txt, a user would enter:

```
 java Sort friends.txt
```

This will run the 'Sort' application and pass in the string array '{'friends.txt'}' with one string in it. Now the application will use this string as the name of the file with the data to sort. The data can be accessed as follows:

```
String fileName = args[0]; // Assuming 'args' is the name of the String array parameter
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).